# Assign values to the nested property

Tags: typescript, angular8

I have a config files where i have created nested properties like below

```
export class Config {
     public msalConfig: {
        auth: {
          authority: string;
          clientId: string;
          validateAuthority: boolean;
          redirectUri: string;
          postLogoutRedirectUri: string;
          navigateToLoginRequestUrl: boolean;
        },
        cache: {};
        scopes: {};
        system: {};
      };
}
```

From ts file i am trying to assign values to the nested properties but it throws error

```
public Settings: Config = null;
this.Settings.msalConfig.auth.redirectUri = window.location.href;
```

Can you tell me how to assign values to the nested properties.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @Alexwayne object is empty

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the inner property of the Settings variable, because it's null, so the `msalConfig` doesn't exist in it yet. You first need to instantiate the Settings to be an object and then you can set the `msalConfig` to some value.

Assign the `Settings` to a new `Config` instance

```cs
private Settings: Config = new Config();
```

then assign a value to the msalConfig like this (in the constructor for instance)

```cs
this.Settings.msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        authority: null,
        clientId: null,
        validateAuthority: false,
        redirectUri: null,
        postLogoutRedirectUri: null,
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false
      },
      cache: {},
      scopes: {},
      system: {}
    };
```

now you can assign value to the redirectUri, just as you wanted to

```cs
this.Settings.msalConfig.auth.redirectUri = window.location.href;
```

Comment: thanks for responding can you tell me how do I do that. Can you help me with this